# How to customize android title bar in fragments onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to change the view of titlebar by typical approach:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle args) {
    ...
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    window.setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.brand_update_layout);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_update_layout, group, false)
            .findViewById(R.id.title_progress);
    TextView title_Text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_update_layout, group, false)
            .findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    title_Text.setText(Html.fromHtml("..."));
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ...
}
```

But this code does not work on some reason. Whats wrong?

**UPD.**
ok, I declared

```
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    window.setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.brand_update_layout);
```

in Activity and

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)getActivity().getWindow().findViewById(R.id.title_progress);
    TextView title_Text = (TextView)getActivity().getWindow().findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    title_Text.setText(...);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

in fragment, however I have an error:

```
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12213): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.quto.ru.CarListFragment.onCreateView(CarListFragment.java:188)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:837)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1041)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:616)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1359)
```

on string `title_Text.setText(...);`

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating a whole new view and trying to find the progressbar / textview in that newly inflated view by using this code:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_update_layout, group, false).findViewById(R.id.title_progress);
TextView title_Text = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.brand_update_layout, group, false).findViewById(R.id.title_text);
```

Try changing it to this

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)window.findViewById(R.id.title_progress);
TextView title_Text = (TextView)window.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
```

Comment: Spot on.  When you set the custom title, the Window object is inflating the custom title for you.  You just need to get references to the inflated views and fill them.